# UITableView and datasource

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add a data source inside a UITableView. I tried the following, but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 8;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set the data for this cell:

    cell.textLabel.text = [_classCellview objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"One";
     cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Two";



    // set the accessory view:
    cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is cellForRowAtIndexPath being called?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I don't see an implementation for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, which is required for `UITableViewDataSource`. Could you post that too?

Comment: Here is my tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.classCellview.count;
}

Comment: Where in my .h file I declared '@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMUtableArray * classCellview'.

Answer (score 0):

> `cell.textLabel.text = [_classCellview objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

You're telling the table that there are 8 sections, but you're not taking the `section` from the index path into account when you populate the cell. An index path has (in the case of a table view) two values: a `section` and a `row`. You need them both to know what cell you're dealing with. So, you're probably getting the same content repeated in each section of your table. (It'd help if you told us exactly what the problem is, though.)

Comment: I have the table displayed, but I want to label field "one" and "two" to display inside of the table.

Comment: In that case, look at what you're doing with the cell's detail label. You're assigning `@"one"` to its `text` property, and then on the next line assigning `@"two"` to the same label. A label can only have one value at a time -- if you want `one two` you should combine the strings first and assign the result to the label.